# Passing a listener to a recycler adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I already know how a recycler viewer works and a good understanding of interface listeners but I'm wondering why is it that we need to pass a listener to my recycler adapter called `mAdapter = new GreenAdapter`. In my `MainActivity.java` I have something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GreenAdapter.ListItemClickListener {

private static final int NUM_LIST_ITEMS = 100;

private GreenAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView mNumbersList;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new GreenAdapter(NUM_LIST_ITEMS, this);
    mNumbersList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex) {
    String toastMessage = "Item #" + clickedItemIndex + "clicked.";
    mToast = Toast.makeText(this, toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mToast.show();

}
```

In my `GreenAdapter.java` I understand that my Viewholder constructor will invoke my custom interface called `ListItemClickedListener` passing in the position of the clicked view and from there I can implement the code for what will happen when the user clicks it through my `onListItemClick` abstract method

```
public class GreenAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GreenAdapter.NumberViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = GreenAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private int mNumberItems;
final private ListItemClickListener mOnClickListener;

public interface ListItemClickListener{
    void onListItemClick(int clickedItemIndex);

}


public GreenAdapter(int numberOfItems, ListItemClickListener listener) {
    mNumberItems = numberOfItems;
    mOnClickListener = listener;
}


@Override
public NumberViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

    Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.number_list_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;
    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    NumberViewHolder viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view);

    return viewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NumberViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "#" + position);
    holder.bind(position);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mNumberItems;
}


class NumberViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

   
    TextView listItemNumberView;

  
    public NumberViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        listItemNumberView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_number);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bind(int listIndex) {
        listItemNumberView.setText(String.valueOf(listIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int clickedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        mOnClickListener.onListItemClick(clickedPosition);
    }
}
```

I'm just confuse why we need to pass `this` in my recycler adapter

Answer (score 0):

By passing `this` you are actually passing the object of `MainActivity.java` which is implementing `GreenAdapter.ListItemClickListener` interface. Now when your user clicks on item you can let your activity know what item in the list was clicked by the user the rest of Business logic will then be written in the `onListItemClick()` method of `MainActivity`.